# Combining tables from different databases through JDBC

Tags: database, excel, jdbc

Is there a way to combine 2 (or more) tables from 2 (or more) different database/connections?

So far, I can only export one table from a database, and this works fine:

```
private void populateWorksheet(Database db, Sheet sheet) {
    PreparedStatement preStmt;              // An object that represents a precompiled SQL statement. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html
    ResultSet rsltSet;                      // A table of data representing a DB result set
    ResultSetMetaData meta;                 // An object that can be used to get information about the types and properties of the columns in a ResultSet object

    String columnName, data;
    Row headerRow, dataRow;
    Cell currHeaderCell, currDataCell;

    int columnCount, rowCount;              // keep track of indices

    try {
        preStmt = db.getConnection().prepareStatement(columnsQuery);
        rsltSet = preStmt.executeQuery();    
        meta = rsltSet.getMetaData();
        columnCount = meta.getColumnCount();

        //Creating a Row for columns headings - starts with row 0
        headerRow = sheet.createRow(HEADER_ROW_INDEX);

        //Get column headings and print them in Excel - on the first row
        for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i ++) {
            columnName = meta.getColumnName(i);
            currHeaderCell = headerRow.createCell(i - 1);
            currHeaderCell.setCellValue(columnName);
        }

        rowCount = FIRST_DATA_ROW_INDEX;    // 1st row after the header row (data/record starts here)

        while(rsltSet.next()) {
            dataRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount);

            for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i ++) {
                data = rsltSet.getString(i);
                currDataCell = dataRow.createCell(i - 1);
                currDataCell.setCellValue(data);
            }
            rowCount ++;
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But what if my application is connected to DatabaseA and DatabaseB and I want to inner-join TableA from DatabaseA and TableB from DatabaseB, and transferring the result to an Excel file. How do I go about in doing this?

EDIT: And what if the databases are in different servers?

Comment: You can't do that directly, you would need to query both datasources and "join" them in code. Or use a database server that can connect to the other database server.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I "join" them in code?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? At least Oracle supports joining data from local tables and remote tables accessed through a _database link_ in the same query.

Comment: I was asked to inner join tables from different databases. Could be from Oracle, Access, or even a SAS dataset.

Answer (score 1):

***If*** the databases reside inside the same DB server *and* your user has permissions in *both*, you can do stuff like

**Mysql**

```
 SELECT * FROM db1.table1 A INNER JOIN db2.table2 B  ON A.col = B.col
```

**SQL-Server** (which default-schema `dbo`)

```
 SELECT * FROM db1.dbo.table1 A INNER JOIN db2.dbo.table2 B  ON A.col = B.col
```

In cases where the databases reside on different servers, your options are more limited.

For SQL-Server you could add a "linked Server" - wich allows access through `linkname...table`.

Comment: Yes, this is helpful. But how about if they are in different servers?

Comment: See my edit - not much you could do there. Except maybe import the tables into in-memory / temporary db and then run your queries against that.

Comment: Since I export columns to Excel anyway, would it be a good idea to just keep editing the same workbook when exporting tables/selected columns from another database?